# No coincidence in numbers in Events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

I have created 3 events: "Place_bet", "Input_select_amount" and "Amount_button". The idea is to track if the user clicks the button with the event "Input_select_amount" OR "Amount_button" AND finally the "Place_bet" button. For this purpose, I have created a sequence like this:
[image]

After this step, I go to see the results, but the numbers don´t fit. If I search for 14th may, the "place bet" event has this result:
[image]

The "Input select amount" this result:
[image]
And the "Amount button" is like this:
[image]

But when I make a sequences filter for the combination of all of them, the result is totally different:
[image]

Any idea of the no result numbers coincidence?

Alejandro.

Comment: What numbers are you expecting? I don't understand what you mean by "no result numbers coincidence".

Comment: If I add the total or unique events in "place bets", input_select_amount" and "amount_button", the result should be the same than in the sequences filter view, but it isn´t :-(

Comment: Your screenshots are huge such that they render unreadable due to the text being so small.  It is hard to tell exactly what information you are paying attention to in each screenshot when you have included so much of the page. Can you edit your question to crop your screenshots to show a smaller area of just the info you are comparing?  Your last screenshot is "hourly" where the first three are "daily", which also makes the comparison hard.  It looks like your first three have just one data point on the graph, so maybe a screen shot isn't the best way to present them anyway, just text is fine.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers look normal to me. Someone who triggers `input_select_amount` but does not trigger `place_bet` afterward will be excluded from your segment, making for fewer `input_select_amount` events in your segment than in All Users. Likewise, you would expect the other events to have smaller totals within this segment than in All Users, and this is what your data shows: 23845 in-segment "select" events (compared to 24163 total), 2033 "button" events (2127 total), and 23518 "bet" events (27605 total).

In your final screenshot, the Total Events and Unique Events values are counting **all** events that happen in the sessions that your segment includes. If you add up the total events for the three events used in your segment definition, you would expect that value to be less than the 204,007 shown for the segment as a whole - in this case much less, since your event `selected_odd_value` is triggered so many times.

Comment: About the final screenshot, are you sure that it is counting ALL events that happen in the sessions that my segment includes? If I segment in the step1 the event "input_select_amount" OR "amount_button", it will ONLY count one of them, not both, isn´t it? (After this, it will also count the event category "place_bet" if it clicked by the user) I mean: it will count the combination of "input_select_amount" + "place_bet" OR "amount_button" + "place_bet"

Comment: The segment doesn't count anything - it looks at each session and asks "did my sequence happen in this session?" If yes, that entire session is included in the data in the report; if no, the entire session is excluded. Does that clarify?

Comment: Then, if yes, it should be less quantity than the sum of Input select amount + Amount button. If I add the Unique events for Input select amount (2510) + Amount button (415) = 2925. In the mean time, for the sequence filter, the result is 17792! I mean: from the 2510 data, there is some of them that are in the sequence group, and the same for the 415. It can never be superior to 2925....

Comment: The Unique Events count you're looking at is for all events that happen in the segment's sessions, not just the events used in the sequence definition. You'll be able to see the unique events for just the events you care about if you go to the Top Events report.

Comment: If the Unique Events count all events that happen in the segment's session, how can I count that the users click first in the input select amount OR Amount button and later he/she clicks the place bet button?...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't get an exact count of that. The number of sessions in the segment will tell you the number of sessions in which that sequence of events happened, but it won't tell you if that sequence happened multiple times. If you can tell on your side whether `place_bet` is preceded by one of the other two events, you can add that information to the event labeling for `place_bet`, but the ability to get at series of actions in GA is pretty limited.

Comment: Oh! what a pity then.....Ok, thanks anyway for your help. Have a nice day :)